# QItemDelegate setModelData in QTreeWidget is not called

Tags: c++, qt4

I am trying to set delegate to my QTreeWidget. The problem is that delegate setModelData is never called. createEditor and setEditorData are called.

Since the editor that I create is simple QLineEdit, commitData() signal doesn't have to be emitted. Also I tried to emit this signal just in case is needed , when editLine editingFinished() was emitted, but that doesn't solve the problem.
As I understand documentaion say that for simple widgets like QLineEdit setModelData should be called without emitting commitData signal, so the following code should work :

```
MyDlg::MyDlg()
{
   mTreeWdg->setItemDelegate(new TestDelegate( this ));
}
MyDlg::OnTreeItemDoubleCliked(QTreeeWidget* item,int column)
{ 
   if(column != 1) return;
   item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEditable);  
   mTreeWdg->editItem(item,column);
}         

TestDelegate::TestDelegate(QObject *parent )
  :QItemDelegate(parent)
  {
  }

 QWidget* TestDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                              const QModelIndex &index) const
{
  if(index.column() == 1) // value column
  {
    QLineEdit* edit = new QLineEdit(parent);      
    return edit;
  }
  else return 0;  // no editor attached
}

void TestDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
   if(index.column() == 1)
   {
      QLineEdit* edit = static_cast<QLineEdit*> (editor);
      edit->setText("damn");
   }
}

void TestDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,const QModelIndex &index) 
{
    if(index.column()!= 1)
      return;
}

void TestDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor,const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}
```

Comment: Sorry problem solved. setModelData was not declared as const

Comment: Wow. I've been trying to fix my QLineEdit delegate for about an hour...Two const definitions was all that was missing xD THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

```
void TestDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,const QModelIndex &index) must be const:

void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,const QModelIndex &index) const
```

Look at the declaration above.